# I want to pre-increment an assignment to a variable (pre-increment by value more than 1)?

Tags: c++, c, pre-increment

I want to pre-increment a value assignment in a for loop

```
for (int x=0; x<100; x+=increase){
   // loop operation here
}
```

The code above post increments the value, however I want to pre increment it. I know I can pre-increment by one with the `++i` syntax, however is there a way to pre increment through variable assignment.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "pre-increment". Assignment is effectively "pre" in that it returns the new value of the variable.

Comment: Replace `x=0` with `x=increase`, if that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: Post- and pre- increment are only meaningful if you use the value of the assignment expression for something, like assigning it to another variable or passing it to a function. You're not doing that here, you're just incrementing the variable and nothing else, so any way you do that is equivalent.

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you have two misconceptions.

1. `x += y` is already "equivalent" to preincrement, in that `x += 1` is, by definition, identical to `++x`.  (The point is that the value of `x += y` is the updated value of x, just as the value of `++x` is the updated value.) It's the postincrement form `x++` that has no exact equivalent for adding increments other than 1.
2. When you write `for(x = 0; x < 100; x += increase)`, you're not immediately using the value of the expression `x += increase`, so it doesn't matter if you use a preincrement or postincrement form.

If you want your loop to start with an initial value of `increase` rather than 0, just write

```
for(x = increase; x < 100; x += increase)
```